# Reactjs issue in capturing form data

Tags: reactjs

I want to capture form data and send it to nodejs backend but it am stuck on issue. whenever i type i shows only that digit in console. Please suggest me solution or give me alternative way of capturing form data. I use .tsx extension for my whole project so it produce little bit difficulties for me

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

const Signup: React.FC = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
    console.log(formData);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const postData = new FormData();
    postData.append("username", formData.username);
    postData.append("email", formData.email);
    postData.append("password", formData.password);
    console.log(postData);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="login-body">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="form-wrapper sign-in">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <h2 className="login-h2">Signup</h2>
              <div className="input-auth">
                <input
                  id="username"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  value={formData.username}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  autoComplete="off"
                />
                <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
              </div>
              <div className="input-auth">
                <input
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  required
                  autoComplete="off"
                  value={formData.email}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              </div>
              <div className="input-auth">
                <input
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                  required
                  value={formData.password}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  autoComplete="off"
                />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              </div>
              <div className="remember">
                <label className="ml-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" /> I agree to the terms & conditions
                </label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="login-button">
                Sign Up
              </button>
              <div className="signUp-link">
                <p>
                  Already have an account?
                  <Link to={"/login"} className="signUpBtn-link">
                    Login
                  </Link>
                </p>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

Conole output is like

```
{username: '', email: '', password: '', "": 's'}
""
: 
"s"
email
: 
""
password
: 
""
username
: 
""
```

It shows only typing character on console and not show text in input frontend. I want to post it to nodejs backend what i do for it

Comment: You need to pass the name attribute to the input tag.

Comment: Thanks .. Work for me . I do with ID just replace with name and got it

Comment: ""
: 
"a"
email
: 
"muhammadhassansaee@gmail.com"
password
: 
"hhahhahahhahah"
username
: 
"Mu Hassan hammadh"          It show one filed extra of empting string with value of current typed characater . it is on index 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console.log(formData) statement is executed immediately after setFormData, which is logging the previous state rather than the updated state.

To fix this, you should use the callback function. Try the modified handleInputChange function:

```
const handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setFormData((prevFormData) => {
    const updatedFormData = {
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    };
    console.log(updatedFormData);
    return updatedFormData;
  });
};
```

Do let me know if this doesn't fix it. Thank you